# Given $X$ is completely regular, can any finite set and closed set be seperated by a contimuous function?

Tags: general-topology

Suppse that $X$ is a space which is completely regular but not completely normal (it might not even be normal).

Let $K=\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ be a finite set in $X$. When can we say that there exists an open set $K \subset U$ and a continuous function $f_k:X \rightarrow \mathbb R$, such that $f(x_i)=0$ for every $x_i \in K$, and $f(x)=1$ for every $x \in U^c$.

I mean, is there an example for a completely regular space, in which, we can seperate single points from closed sets by a continuous functions, but can not seperate finite sets from closed sets by a comtinuous function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete regularity is best phrased in terms of the existence of certain continuous functions into the closed unit interval $[0,1]$ (and doesn't affect at all the class itself).

**Hint:** If $f,g : X \to [0,1]$ are continuous, so is $h: x \mapsto \min \{ f(x) , g(x) \}$.

Comment: I see, so, if for any $x_i$ there exists a continuous function $f_i$, that seperates $x_i$ from $U^c$, then $f=min \{f_i\}$ is continuous and seperates $K$ from $U^c$.. ok Thanks!